# Add a div at top of WooCommerce shortcode output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I have a WooCommerce product list generated by the `[products category='tshirts']` shortcode.

I would like to add a div to the top of the list, so it looks like this:

```
<div class='woocommerce'>
   <ul class='products'>
       <div class='test'>Hello</div> //This is the div I would like to add
       <li class='product'></li>
       <li class='product'></li>
       <li class='product'></li>
       ...
```

I have tried the following but it is still not working:

```php
function action_woocommerce_shop_loop( $array, $int ) { 
    echo "<div class='test'>Hello</div>";
}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop', 10, 2 );
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options are possible:

**1.** Re-write the `woocommerce_product_loop_start` function which is pluggable

```php
function woocommerce_product_loop_start( $echo = true ) {
    ob_start();

    wc_set_loop_prop( 'loop', 0 );

    wc_get_template( 'loop/loop-start.php' );
    
    // Loop prop name = products
    if ( wc_get_loop_prop('name') == 'products' ) {
        echo '<div class="test">Hello</div>';
    }

    $loop_start = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', ob_get_clean() );

    if ( $echo ) {      
        // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
        echo $loop_start;
    } else {
        return $loop_start;
    }
}
```

---

---

**2.** Overwrite the [loop/loop-start.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/templates/loop/loop-start.php) template file. This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php`

Replace

```php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>
<ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">
```

With

```php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>
<ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">
<?php
// Loop prop name = products
if ( wc_get_loop_prop('name') == 'products' ) {
    echo '<div class="test">Hello</div>';
}
?>
```

---

---

**3.** Via `do_action( "woocommerce_shortcode_before_{$this->type}_loop", $this->attributes );`

```php
function action_woocommerce_shortcode_before_products_loop( $atts ) {   
    echo "<div class='test'>Hello</div>";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_before_products_loop', 'action_woocommerce_shortcode_before_products_loop', 10, 1 );
```

Result: (However, this is not quite what you are looking for)

```
<div class='woocommerce'>
   <div class='test'>Hello</div> //This is the div I would like to add
   <ul class='products'>
       <li class='product'></li>
       <li class='product'></li>
```